# Setup server to upload and store files from multiple users

Tags: ssh, debian

I want to setup a server where documents from users will be uploaded and stored for access from a web interface. I am using a Debian-based web server and will have potentially thousands of users accessing their files. Files will be uploaded via scp or rsync.

What would be the best hierarchical structure for such an application?

Would I need to create a separate user account (and home directory) for each user in order for them to be able to access their own files, but not those of any other user? My concern would be that I may end up with potentially thousands of user accounts and therefore home directories which would take up many assets. Each user only requires one folder to hold all their uploaded files.

What assets (cpu, HDD space, etc) of the server determine how many user accounts I can create?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A modern Linux kernel can support 2<sup>32</sup> user accounts so with just 'thousands' there isn't anything to really worry about in respect of the number of accounts. Giving everyone their own shouldn't be an issue.

Ensure you have sufficient disc space and that you can add more as required so use a [Logical Volume Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)). It would be a good idea to use some sort of [RAID](https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them) (or a filesystem like [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS)) to aid availability.

You should carefully research different filesystems and choose one that suits your expected workload.

One thing to consider is [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) these can become exhausted, ensure that your filessytem supports enough for your expected usage. If necessary also ensure that you create sufficient when initialising the filesystem.